# Pass variable into button_click procedure

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to pass a variable into a button_click procedure?

**Background:**

I have 2 procedures, both of which perform some actions, and then both open Form_1. Now, dependant on which procedure opened Form_1, I want the command button to perform a different task with the data on the form. Ordinarily, I would pass a variable from the first procedure into the procedure being called.

However, due to it being a form being called, which requires the user to click the command button to initiate the second procedure, I do not think it's possible to pass a variable to this procedure?

For now I assign a public  variable in procedure_1: `override = False` and procedure_2: `override = True`, but I know it's generally frowned upon to use public variables (from what I have read).

Within the button_click procedure I then use this variable to route the code accordingly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If override Then
        Call override_data
    Else
        Call submit_data
    End If
End Sub
```

Am I okay, in this scenario, to use a public variable? or is there a better way to achieve my target?

Comment: "Depending on which procedure opened form_1" - does this mean there are two different buttons that can be clicked to open the form? Or that the form is opened first (one of two ways) and you want the button to know that?

Comment: Correct with the first assumption; there are 2 different buttons which can be clicked on a userform, which then run one of the procedures which leads to form_1 opening.

Comment: Why not assign each procedure to a different button? Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: It is OK to use a Public variable - I'd put it in the form and set it before showing the form - though a Property procedure in the form would be better practice.

Comment: Yeah, that could be another workaround, although for the user it would make sense if they're pressing the same button. Thanks for pointing that out! I was more after the knowledge of where it's possible to somehow pass a variable into a button_click procedure.

Comment: Thanks Rory - would you mind elaborating on how I would use a property procedure to approach this?

Comment: Look at Jon Peltier's [explanation](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/PropertyProcedures.html) to learn how to set and read user form properties. This should solve your problem and avoid a public variable.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks PeterT - I've only ever used properties as part of Class modules before, never within forms. If you want to put that as the answer I will accept it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reading [Jon Peltier's article](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/PropertyProcedures.html) on user form properties, as suggested in the comments by @PeterT.

This enabled me to use a user form property instead of a public variable.